# Como puedo obtener los cambios de un proyecto en TFS y mostrarlo en consola

Tags: c#, tfs

Necesito obtener los cambios realizados en el proyecto según seleccione la colección, por ejemplo si selecciono la **colección A** si tengo cambios en el proyecto que esta dentro de esa colección que me los muestre en la consola el archivo o archivos que fueron modificados.

Este es el código que hasta el momento tengo:

```
        using (var tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false, new UICredentialsProvider()))
        {

            var result = tpp.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
                tfsTeamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
                VersionControlServer versionControlServer = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
                var workSpaces = versionControlServer.QueryWorkspaces(null, @"USUARIO", Environment.MachineName);

                Workspace workSpace = workSpaces[0];
                foreach (WorkingFolder folder in workSpace.Folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.ServerItem);
                }
            }

        }

        Console.Read();
    }

   
}
```